# checking two arrays in python which has two same value in an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have two arrays and I'm trying to find values ​​that are in the first array but not in the second array. However, there is a problem, although there are two b's in the first array, since there is only one b in the other array, it sees that it is the same and gives the output that there is no difference. How can I solve this problem?

```
x = ["a","b","b"]
y = ["a","b"]

print(set(x)-set(y))
```

Comment: An approach to take would be to go through one array, get the count of each value in the array, and do the same for the second. Then, iterate over each value and its count for the first array, and check if the second array has the same count for each value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter

res = [k for k, v in (Counter(x) - Counter(y)).items() for _ in range(v)]
```

The complexity of this approach is the best you can get (i.e., O(n)).

Example:

```
>>> x = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5]
>>> y = [1,2,4]
>>> res = [k for k, v in (Counter(x) - Counter(y)).items() for _ in range(v)]
>>> res
[2, 2, 3, 5]
```

You're going to loose the order of your elements with this approach. Let me know if that's not good in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue

```
 for i in y:
     if (i in x):
         x.remove(i)
 print(x)
```

Comment: This has a O(n^2) complexity, which might be too much when arrays are large

Comment: I agree, for quick scripting, this should work. for large workflows not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

My approach woul be list comprehension:

```
x = ["a","b","b"]
y = ["a","b"]

[x.remove(element) for element in y if element in x]
```

Output:

```
['b']
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks a simple solution:
`a==b`

```
>>> b=["1","2","3"]
>>> a=["1","2","3"]
>>> a==b
True
>>> a=["1","2","32"]
>>> a==b
False
>>> a=["1","2","2"]
>>> a==b
False
>>> a=["1","2","3","4"]
>>> a==b
False
>>> a=["1","2","3"]
>>> a==b
True
>>> a=["1","2"]
>>> a==b
False
>>> a=["1","3","2"]
>>> a==b
False
>>> a=["1","2","3"]
>>> a==b
True
```